# How to click on a Transparent form in

Tags: vb.net

I made a ScreenCapture Program in VB.Net. I already have the Region and Dragging Forms without border's code. But my Problem is i cannot drag a form if it is transparent.

Here's the Image:
[image]

That Faded Black part is the Form1 and is an MDI Container. The Transparent part is my Form2 and is the Childform.

My Question:
How do i drag that child form? because when i try to click on it, it will just click the thing on whats behind it. Let's say that Badges button of Stackoverflow. Anyone Can help me with this?

Here's my Files if you want to experiment with it.
[Try.zip](https://www.myflare.com/0/filedata/get/gVnrCNpxEeOqYCIFCuMzIQ?download=true)

Comment: You can't click on a completely transparent form. Try setting a very low opacity instead so that it appears transparent.

Comment: I tried 10% on my Child Form but it will only depends on the Opacity of my Parent Form. How can i change my child form Opacity that will not depend on my Parent form? Any idea sir?

Comment: Well you can use any value as long as it is greater than 0, so try 1% instead.

Comment: My child form would only match its parent form's opacity :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better option would be to have a regular form, on which you would place contents underneath it (bitmap copy), so it appears as though you are looking at the desktop, while instead you are looking at the form. Then you can fade in, or fade out areas at will, using GDI+ or DirectX, and your mouse clicks should be registered just fine.

Comment: I must try it. Thanks for your answer by the way. :)